# mitmproxy: Ignore host when ssl handshake fails

Tags: linux, man-in-the-middle

I'm checking the network security of a device on my network, and I'm using mitmproxy. My device appears to be verifying the first couple certificates (mitmproxy keeps saying "Client Handshake failed"), but after a few failed handshakes, my device throws an error and stops (and understandably so). So I can't verify any of the other certificates, since the device stops communicating.

I could manually add each server to the ignore list as soon as I know it's good, but that would take too long (my device has many applications which access many different servers).

I would like to set up mitmproxy to put the destination on an "ignore" list as soon as a handshake fails. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a way to do this. You just have to write an add-on script, and include the name of the script as an argument to the mitmproxy command. The methods in the script can control mitmproxy's behavior.

In fact, there's an example script in the Github repository that does the exact thing I wanted to do:
https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/examples/complex/tls_passthrough.py